# C++ run void async or in task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am kinda new to C++ and I want to run a void async or in a task.
In C# it would look like this:

```
 var taskA = new Task(() => { Popupmessage("Hi"); });
 taskA.Start();
```

How could I convert that to C++?

I found something like this and tried:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, Popupmessage("Hi"));
```

but that doesn't work as I think I used the wrong code here.

Comment: Elaborate _"doesn't work"_

Comment: `std::async(std::launch::async, []() { Popupmessage("Hi") });` or use `[&]` if Popupmessage is a member function.

Comment: - Error Message saying: "std::async": no matching overloaded function found.
- Error specializing function template "std::future<_Select_invoke_traits<decay<_Ty>::type,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)".

Comment: @super that did work thanks a lot :)

Comment: Be sure to catch the returned future or it will effectively run synchronously. The destructor calls wait.